# JNI: equivalent of uint *vboIds in Java

Tags: java, c, arrays, java-native-interface

I'm developing a java application that uses some jni calls.

I have on C code the following variable:

```
GLuint *vboIds;
```

I want to pass this variable from **Java** to **C**, but I don't know how to declare it in Java.

`GLuint` is equivalent an unsigned `int`.

So, I think this is the equivalent declaration in Java:

```
int[] vboIds;
```

What do you think?

Thanks

Comment: Seems to be correct. Have you tried your solution?

Comment: In case you are trying to do OpenGL things in Java: it might be easier to use one of the existing Java OpenGL bindings, see http://jogamp.org/ or http://www.lwjgl.org/

Comment: @Vladimir Ivanov: it's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say explicitly whether it is meant to be a pointer to a single value or an array, but I'd guess it's probably an array from the naming and what you are thinking of doing with the mapping (there should also be a parameter somewhere that specifies the length of the array; those both map to the *same* argument on the Java side as Java's arrays know their own lengths). You're probably right to use an `int` as that's generally the same size as a C `int` – not that that's a guarantee, not at all, but hardly any machine architectures are different from that these days – but you'll need to watch out for the fact that Java's numeric types are all signed. That's mostly not a problem provided you're a bit careful with arithmetic (other than addition, subtraction and left-shift, which work obviously) and comparisons.

Comment: vboIds will contains one or two values.

Comment: @Vans: Even so, my advice still holds. You seem to be approaching things in a reasonable way; the mapping you've chosen at least looks to be the right one for your first attempt, as it's the closest in terms of general datatypes and sizes.